# Hacer una operación en un hilo diferente al principal en Java

Tags: java, hilos

Buenas, estoy intentado calcular una operación en un hilo secundario, o sea, diferente al main para evitar que se trabe el hilo principal, ya que a veces el tiempo que requiere la operación es muy grande. 
La variable resultado es una variable del JFrame Form que ejecuto en el hilo principal.

```
Thread espacio_calculo = new Thread(() -> {  
                            resultado = String.valueOf(CBinomial.bin_r(new BigInteger(n), new BigInteger(k)));
});
espacio_calculo.start();                          
txtAreaBin.setText(resultado);  //Aquí muestro el resultado en un JTextArea en el hilo principal.
```

Me tira problemas acerca de las variables locales.
Estuve practicando con un ejemplo aparte y veo que el problema es al asignar a la variable de un hilo diferente, puedo operarlas, mostrarlas, etc. Pero no puedo asignarle nada.
  [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Dos cosas: 1. Por favor en lugar de colocar una imagen de tu código, coloca el código relevante en forma textual. Así facilita su uso en la plataforma. 2. Si has encontrado una solución, por favor evita actualizar la pregunta. En su lugar, publica una respuesta indicando lo que usaste para resolver la situación.

Comment: No hay que disculparse, estamos para aprender. Quizás suena un poco "duro" mi forma de escribir, pero bueno, como developer, solemos no tener corazón xD

Comment: Ah, borré el comentario porque me pareció redundante lo que dije ya que noté que tu fuiste quien respondió al problema. Jejeje lo tendré en cuenta, se que igualmente lo dijiste amablemente. Soy aún muy nuevo por acá, intento adaptarme a las reglas ya que me parece una gran plataforma.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tienes dos problemas:

1. La variable `resultado` debe definirse **dentro** del alcance del trabajo del hilo. Esto es porque una clase anónima no puede modificar los valores<sup>1</sup> de las variables que estén fuera de su alcance.
2. Actualizar el estado de tu `txtAreaBin` debe hacerse dentro del trabajo del hilo. Hacerlo fuera no tiene mucho sentido puesto que la variable `resultado` quizás no haya sido actualizada por el trabajo del hilo.

Tomando en cuenta lo anterior, tu código debería modificarse a:

```
//comentar o remover esta línea, no es necesario
//String resultado = "";
//resto del código...
Thread espacio_calculo = new Thread(() -> {  
    String resultado = String.valueOf(CBinomial.bin_r(new BigInteger(n), new BigInteger(k)));
    txtAreaBin.setText(resultado);
});
espacio_calculo.start();
```

Si estás trabajando con Swing, en lugar de usar un `Thread` para modificar el estado de los campos visibles, deberías hacerlo mediante [`SwingWorker`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html).

---

<sup>1</sup> Nota: solo el valor de una variable, es decir, la asignación. Si tu variable posee estado, sí se puede modificar. Pero considera que este es un tópico más complejo.

Comment: ¡Muchísimas gracias por la explicación, había asumido que no podía asignarla por ser "contextos diferentes" pero con tu explicación me queda muchísimo mas claro, me interesa esa cuestión de los estados, pero bueno, será a su momento, te doy la solución por la explicación. Gracias.

Answer (score 2):

- No puedes asignar una variable local desde una clase anónima, porque la variable local tiene que ser `final` para poder ser usado dentro de la clase anónima.
- Tu arrancas el `Thread` y sin esperar el resultado actualizas `txtAreaBin`. Eso va pasar antes de poder recibir el resultado.

Para lograr lo que quieres hacer, debes usar:

```
    Thread espacio_calculo = new Thread( () ->{
            txtAreaBin.setText(String.valueOf(CBinomial.bin_r(new BigInteger(n), new BigInteger(k))));
    });
    espacio_calculo.start();
```

Answer (score 1):

Yo haría lo siguiente ya que el hilo principal calcula, cuando termine de hacer ese calculo que llame al método que cree llamado **mostrarResultado** y así ya te debe funcionar según entendí lo que buscas hacer.
Nota: Estoy considerando que estan en metodos separados y no en el mismo metodo

```
 //metodo del hilo
    private void mihilo(){
         Thread espacio_calculo = new Thread(() -> {  
                                        resultado = String.valueOf(CBinomial.bin_r(new BigInteger(n), new BigInteger(k)));
            mostrarResultado(resultado);
            });
            espacio_calculo.start(); 
    }

//metodo que muestra el resultado
    private void mostrarResultado(String resultado){
         txtAreaBin.setText(resultado);  //Aquí muestro el resultado en un JTextArea en el hilo principal.
}
```

Comment: Nada amigo, sigue dando el mismo error, no hay diferencia.

Comment: tienes captura o la pagina del codigo completo para poder ayudarte mejor

Comment: Ya añado la captura. Quite el error intentando mostrar por consola el valor, pero no me da nada, el que ejecuto es el del else.

Comment: Resultado del if lo quitaste?

Comment: Si, ahí me da el problema. No me deja asignarle a la variable de clase dentro del hilo.

Comment: Logré lo que quería con el código que acabo de dejar, no sabía que no podía asignarle variables de clase a otro hilo.

Comment: Bien amigo, lo bueno es que se logro, trabajas con netbeans

Comment: Efectivamente..

Comment: Yo tengo creado un hilo en la clase principal declarandolo arriba, implementado la clase runnable en mi jframe, luego declaras el método run, y en ese pones tu código, ya solo seria que en el boton pongas el start, solo hay que tener cuidado ya que si se termina el hilo después de poner start hay que crearlo de nuevo, eso lo solucionas con una validación, yo lo uso para la carga de datos en la vista y para que no se vea trabajo el jframe